# Design an algorithm to predict words based on a skeleton from a given dictionary

Tags: algorithms, strings, python, mathematical-analysis

I'm working on an algorithm which is permitted to use a training set of approximately 250,000 dictionary words.

I have built and providing here with a basic, working algorithm. This algorithm will match the provided masked string (e.g. a _ _ l e) to all possible words in the dictionary, tabulate the frequency of letters appearing in these possible words, and then guess the letter with the highest frequency of appearence that has not already been guessed. If there are no remaining words that match then it will default back to the character frequency distribution of the entire dictionary.

This benchmark strategy is successful approximately 10% of the time. I aim to design an algorithm that significantly outperforms this benchmark.

```
class HangmanAPI(object):
    def __init__(self, access_token=None, session=None, timeout=None):
        self.hangman_url = self.determine_hangman_url()
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.session = session or requests.Session()
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.guessed_letters = []

        full_dictionary_location = "words_250000_train.txt"
        self.full_dictionary = self.build_dictionary(full_dictionary_location)
        self.full_dictionary_common_letter_sorted = collections.Counter("".join(self.full_dictionary)).most_common()

        self.current_dictionary = []

        # Initialize the decision tree, random forest, and SVM models along with the vectorizer
        self.decision_tree_model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        self.random_forest_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
        self.svm_model = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, random_state=42)
        self.vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', lowercase=False, binary=True)
        self.target_labels = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(26)]

        # Fit the decision tree model with the full dictionary once during initialization
        X = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(self.full_dictionary)
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.full_dictionary])
        self.decision_tree_model.fit(X, y)

        # Add Q-table to store Q-values for state-action pairs
        self.q_table = {}

        # Hyperparameters for Q-learning
        self.learning_rate = 0.1
        self.discount_factor = 0.9
        self.epsilon = 0.1  # Probability of exploration during action selection

    def update_q_table(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
        # Q-learning update rule
        current_q_value = self.q_table.get((state, action), 0.0)
        next_q_values = [self.q_table.get((next_state, next_action), 0.0) for next_action in self.target_labels]
        max_next_q_value = max(next_q_values)
        new_q_value = current_q_value + self.learning_rate * (reward + self.discount_factor * max_next_q_value - current_q_value)
        self.q_table[(state, action)] = new_q_value

    def extract_features(self, word_pattern):
        # Extract features from the word pattern
        features = []

        # Word Length
        features.append(len(word_pattern))

        # Vowel and Consonant Counts
        vowel_count = sum(1 for letter in word_pattern if letter in 'aeiou')
        consonant_count = sum(1 for letter in word_pattern if letter in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz')
        features.append(vowel_count)
        features.append(consonant_count)

        # Common Letter Count
        common_letters = set("etaoinsrhldcumfpgwybvkxjqz")
        common_letter_count = sum(1 for letter in word_pattern if letter in common_letters)
        features.append(common_letter_count)

        # Letter Position Features
        features.append(1 if word_pattern.startswith('a') else 0)  # Check if starts with 'a'
        features.append(1 if word_pattern.endswith('e') else 0)  # Check if ends with 'e'
        features.append(1 if 'qu' in word_pattern else 0)  # Check if contains 'qu'

        # Character N-grams
        n_grams = [word_pattern[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(word_pattern) - 1)]
        for n_gram in ['th', 'er', 'in', 'ou', 'an']:  # Example: Consider the presence of common letter pairs
            features.append(1 if n_gram in n_grams else 0)

        # Part-of-Speech (POS) Features - Not implemented here, requires external NLP tools

        # Syllable Count - Not implemented here

        # Letter Frequency Distribution - Not implemented here

        return features

    def hyperparameter_tuning(self):
        # Define the hyperparameter search spaces for each model using hyperopt
        dt_space = {
            'criterion': hp.choice('criterion', ['gini', 'entropy']),
            'splitter': hp.choice('splitter', ['best', 'random']),
            'max_depth': hp.choice('max_depth', [None, 10, 20, 30]),
            'min_samples_split': hp.choice('min_samples_split', [2, 5, 10]),
            'min_samples_leaf': hp.choice('min_samples_leaf', [1, 2, 4])
        }

        rf_space = {
            'n_estimators': hp.choice('n_estimators', [100, 200, 300]),
            'criterion': hp.choice('criterion', ['gini', 'entropy']),
            'max_depth': hp.choice('max_depth', [None, 10, 20, 30]),
            'min_samples_split': hp.choice('min_samples_split', [2, 5, 10]),
            'min_samples_leaf': hp.choice('min_samples_leaf', [1, 2, 4]),
            'bootstrap': hp.choice('bootstrap', [True, False])
        }

        svm_space = {
            'C': hp.loguniform('C', -3, 1),  # Search space for C in log scale
            'kernel': hp.choice('kernel', ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid']),
            'gamma': hp.choice('gamma', ['scale', 'auto'])
        }

        # Perform Bayesian optimization for Decision Tree
        dt_best = fmin(fn=self.hyperopt_objective, space=dt_space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=50, verbose=0)
        self.decision_tree_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(
            criterion=dt_best['criterion'],
            splitter=dt_best['splitter'],
            max_depth=dt_best['max_depth'],
            min_samples_split=dt_best['min_samples_split'],
            min_samples_leaf=dt_best['min_samples_leaf']
        )

        # Perform Bayesian optimization for Random Forest
        rf_best = fmin(fn=self.hyperopt_objective, space=rf_space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=50, verbose=0)
        self.random_forest_model = RandomForestClassifier(
            n_estimators=rf_best['n_estimators'],
            criterion=rf_best['criterion'],
            max_depth=rf_best['max_depth'],
            min_samples_split=rf_best['min_samples_split'],
            min_samples_leaf=rf_best['min_samples_leaf'],
            bootstrap=rf_best['bootstrap']
        )

        # Perform Bayesian optimization for SVM
        svm_best = fmin(fn=self.hyperopt_objective, space=svm_space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=50, verbose=0)
        self.svm_model = SVC(
            C=svm_best['C'],
            kernel=svm_best['kernel'],
            gamma=svm_best['gamma']
        )

    def hyperopt_objective(self, params):
        X = self.vectorizer.transform(self.current_dictionary)
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.current_dictionary])

        model = DecisionTreeClassifier(**params)
        cv_score = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5).mean()
        return -cv_score

    def genetic_algorithm_tuning(self):
        # Define the hyperparameter search spaces for each model
        dt_space = {
            'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
            'splitter': ['best', 'random'],
            'max_depth': [None, 10, 20, 30],
            'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
            'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4]
        }

        rf_space = {
            'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
            'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
            'max_depth': [None, 10, 20, 30],
            'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
            'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],
            'bootstrap': [True, False]
        }

        svm_space = {
            'C': [0.1, 1, 10],
            'kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid'],
            'gamma': ['scale', 'auto']
        }

        # Perform Genetic Algorithm optimization for Decision Tree
        dt_genetic_algorithm = ga(function=self.genetic_algorithm_objective, dimension=len(dt_space), variable_type='int', variable_boundaries=[(0, len(dt_space[key]) - 1) for key in dt_space])
        dt_best_idx = dt_genetic_algorithm.run()
        dt_best = {list(dt_space.keys())[i]: dt_space[list(dt_space.keys())[i]][idx] for i, idx in enumerate(dt_best_idx)}
        self.decision_tree_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(
            criterion=dt_best['criterion'],
            splitter=dt_best['splitter'],
            max_depth=dt_best['max_depth'],
            min_samples_split=dt_best['min_samples_split'],
            min_samples_leaf=dt_best['min_samples_leaf']
        )

        # Perform Genetic Algorithm optimization for Random Forest
        rf_genetic_algorithm = ga(function=self.genetic_algorithm_objective, dimension=len(rf_space), variable_type='int', variable_boundaries=[(0, len(rf_space[key]) - 1) for key in rf_space])
        rf_best_idx = rf_genetic_algorithm.run()
        rf_best = {list(rf_space.keys())[i]: rf_space[list(rf_space.keys())[i]][idx] for i, idx in enumerate(rf_best_idx)}
        self.random_forest_model = RandomForestClassifier(
            n_estimators=rf_best['n_estimators'],
            criterion=rf_best['criterion'],
            max_depth=rf_best['max_depth'],
            min_samples_split=rf_best['min_samples_split'],
            min_samples_leaf=rf_best['min_samples_leaf'],
            bootstrap=rf_best['bootstrap']
        )

        # Perform Genetic Algorithm optimization for SVM
        svm_genetic_algorithm = ga(function=self.genetic_algorithm_objective, dimension=len(svm_space), variable_type='int', variable_boundaries=[(0, len(svm_space[key]) - 1) for key in svm_space])
        svm_best_idx = svm_genetic_algorithm.run()
        svm_best = {list(svm_space.keys())[i]: svm_space[list(svm_space.keys())[i]][idx] for i, idx in enumerate(svm_best_idx)}
        self.svm_model = SVC(
            C=svm_best['C'],
            kernel=svm_best['kernel'],
            gamma=svm_best['gamma']
        )

    def genetic_algorithm_objective(self, idxs):
        X = self.vectorizer.transform(self.current_dictionary)
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.current_dictionary])

        dt_space = {
            'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
            'splitter': ['best', 'random'],
            'max_depth': [None, 10, 20, 30],
            'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
            'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4]
        }

        rf_space = {
            'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
            'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
            'max_depth': [None, 10, 20, 30],
            'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
            'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],
            'bootstrap': [True, False]
        }

        svm_space = {
            'C': [0.1, 1, 10],
            'kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid'],
            'gamma': ['scale', 'auto']
        }

        dt_best = {list(dt_space.keys())[i]: dt_space[list(dt_space.keys())[i]][idx] for i, idx in enumerate(idxs)}
        rf_best = {list(rf_space.keys())[i]: rf_space[list(rf_space.keys())[i]][idx] for i, idx in enumerate(idxs)}
        svm_best = {list(svm_space.keys())[i]: svm_space[list(svm_space.keys())[i]][idx] for i, idx in enumerate(idxs)}

        dt_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(
            criterion=dt_best['criterion'],
            splitter=dt_best['splitter'],
            max_depth=dt_best['max_depth'],
            min_samples_split=dt_best['min_samples_split'],
            min_samples_leaf=dt_best['min_samples_leaf']
        )
        dt_cv_score = cross_val_score(dt_model, X, y, cv=5).mean()

        rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(
            n_estimators=rf_best['n_estimators'],
            criterion=rf_best['criterion'],
            max_depth=rf_best['max_depth'],
            min_samples_split=rf_best['min_samples_split'],
            min_samples_leaf=rf_best['min_samples_leaf'],
            bootstrap=rf_best['bootstrap']
        )
        rf_cv_score = cross_val_score(rf_model, X, y, cv=5).mean()

        svm_model = SVC(
            C=svm_best['C'],
            kernel=svm_best['kernel'],
            gamma=svm_best['gamma']
        )
        svm_cv_score = cross_val_score(svm_model, X, y, cv=5).mean()

        return -(dt_cv_score + rf_cv_score + svm_cv_score) / 3

    def train_all_models(self):
        X = self.vectorizer.transform(self.full_dictionary)
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.full_dictionary])

        # Fit all models with the full dictionary
        self.decision_tree_model.fit(X, y)
        self.random_forest_model.fit(X, y)
        self.svm_model.fit(X, y)

        # Perform hyperparameter tuning for Decision Tree, Random Forest, and SVM models
        self.hyperparameter_tuning()

        # Train the neural network model and perform fine-tuning
        self.train_neural_network()
        self.fine_tune_neural_network()
        
    def word_to_numeric(self, word):
        # Convert word pattern to a binary sequence of guessed (1) and not guessed (0) letters
        return [1 if letter in self.guessed_letters else 0 for letter in word]

    def ensemble_guess(self, word_pattern):
        numeric_word_pattern = self.word_to_numeric(word_pattern)
    
        # Get predictions from all three models
        dt_guess = self.decision_tree_model.predict([numeric_word_pattern])[0]
        rf_guess = self.random_forest_model.predict([numeric_word_pattern])[0]
        svm_guess = self.svm_model.predict([numeric_word_pattern])[0]

        # Create a list of all model predictions
        ensemble_guesses = [dt_guess, rf_guess, svm_guess]

        # Use voting to determine the final prediction
        guessed_letter = max(set(ensemble_guesses), key=ensemble_guesses.count)

        return guessed_letter
        
    @staticmethod
    def determine_hangman_url():
        links = ['https://trexsim.com', 'https://sg.trexsim.com']

        data = {link: 0 for link in links}

        for link in links:
            requests.get(link)

            for i in range(10):
                s = time.time()
                requests.get(link)
                data[link] = time.time() - s

        link = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0]
        link += '/trexsim/hangman'
        return link

    def train_neural_network(self):
        X = self.vectorizer.transform(self.current_dictionary)
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.current_dictionary])

        # Convert the word patterns to images (2D arrays)
        X_images = self.patterns_to_images(X.toarray(), self.vectorizer.vocabulary_)

        # Initialize and configure the convolutional neural network model
        neural_net_model = Sequential()
        neural_net_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(X_images.shape[1], X_images.shape[2], 1)))
        neural_net_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        neural_net_model.add(Flatten())
        neural_net_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
        neural_net_model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        neural_net_model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))
        neural_net_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Convert labels to one-hot encoding
        y_onehot = np.zeros((y.shape[0], 26))
        for i, letter in enumerate(y):
            y_onehot[i, ord(letter) - ord('a')] = 1

        # Train the neural network model
        neural_net_model.fit(X_images, y_onehot, epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

        # Store the trained model in the HangmanAPI object
        self.neural_net_model = neural_net_model

    def patterns_to_images(self, patterns, vocabulary):
        # Convert the patterns to images (2D arrays) with 0s and 1s
        max_pattern_length = max(len(pattern) for pattern in patterns)
        images = []
        for pattern in patterns:
            image = [0] * max_pattern_length
            for i, letter in enumerate(pattern):
                if letter in vocabulary:
                    image[i] = 1
            images.append(image)

        # Reshape the images to (num_samples, pattern_length, 1)
        images = np.array(images)
        return images.reshape(images.shape[0], images.shape[1], 1)
    
    def fine_tune_neural_network(self):
        X = self.vectorizer.transform(self.current_dictionary)
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.current_dictionary])

        # Initialize and configure the neural network model
        neural_net_model = Sequential()
        neural_net_model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
        neural_net_model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        neural_net_model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))

        # Compile the model with the 'adam' optimizer
        neural_net_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Convert labels to one-hot encoding
        y_onehot = np.zeros((y.shape[0], 26))
        for i, letter in enumerate(y):
            y_onehot[i, ord(letter) - ord('a')] = 1

        # Fine-tune the neural network model
        neural_net_model.fit(X.toarray(), y_onehot, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

        # Store the fine-tuned model in the HangmanAPI object
        self.neural_net_model = neural_net_model

    def guess(self, word):
        # Clean the word so that we strip away the space characters
        # Replace "_" with "." as "." indicates any character in regular expressions
        clean_word = word[::2].replace("_", ".")

        # Find length of the passed word
        len_word = len(clean_word)

        # Grab current dictionary of possible words from self object, initialize a new possible words dictionary to empty
        current_dictionary = self.current_dictionary
        new_dictionary = []

        # Iterate through all of the words in the old plausible dictionary
        for dict_word in current_dictionary:
            # Continue if the word is not of the appropriate length
            if len(dict_word) != len_word:
                continue

            # If dictionary word is a possible match, then add it to the current dictionary
            if re.match(clean_word, dict_word):
                new_dictionary.append(dict_word)

        # Update Q-table state for the current word pattern
        current_state = clean_word

        # With probability epsilon, explore by choosing a random letter
        if random.random() < self.epsilon:
            # Randomly select a letter from the target labels
            guessed_letter = random.choice(self.target_labels)
        else:
            # With probability (1 - epsilon), exploit by choosing the letter with the highest Q-value
            # Choose the letter with the highest Q-value for the current state
            q_values_for_state = {action: self.q_table.get((current_state, action), 0.0) for action in self.target_labels}
            guessed_letter = max(q_values_for_state, key=q_values_for_state.get)

        # Update Q-table state for the next word pattern after making the guess
        next_word_pattern = word.replace("_", guessed_letter)
        next_state = next_word_pattern[::2].replace("_", ".")

        # Update the Q-table based on the observed reward and the next state
        # We don't have access to the actual reward in this implementation, so set it to 0 for now
        reward = 0
        self.update_q_table(current_state, guessed_letter, reward, next_state)

        # Overwrite old possible words dictionary with the updated version
        self.current_dictionary = new_dictionary

        # If there are no remaining words that match, default back to the ordering of the full dictionary
        if not new_dictionary:
            sorted_letter_count = self.full_dictionary_common_letter_sorted
        else:
            # Update the current dictionary with the new_dictionary
            self.current_dictionary = new_dictionary

            # Get the count of each letter at each position in the current dictionary
            letter_counts = [{letter: sum(1 for word in self.current_dictionary if word[i] == letter) for letter in self.target_labels}
                            for i in range(len(clean_word))]

            # Choose the character with the highest count at the next position
            next_position = len(self.guessed_letters)

            # If all letters have been guessed, use fallback guess from full dictionary ordering
            if next_position >= len(letter_counts):
                return self.ensemble_guess(clean_word)

            guessed_letter = max(letter_counts[next_position], key=letter_counts[next_position].get)

            # Remove the guessed letter from the possible letters in current_dictionary
            self.current_dictionary = [word for word in self.current_dictionary if guessed_letter not in word]

            return guessed_letter

        # Return the letter with the highest information gain that hasn't been guessed yet
        for letter, info_gain in sorted_letter_count:
            if letter not in self.guessed_letters:
                return letter

        # If all letters have been guessed, revert to ordering of full dictionary (fallback)
        return self.ensemble_guess(clean_word)

    def make_decision(self, word_pattern, models=['dt', 'rf', 'svm'], use_neural_net=True):
        # Clean the word pattern so that we strip away the space characters
        # Replace "_" with "." as "." indicates any character in regular expressions
        clean_word = word_pattern[::2].replace("_", ".")

        # Filter the full dictionary to get the current dictionary of possible words
        self.current_dictionary = [word for word in self.full_dictionary if re.match(clean_word, word)]

        # If there are no remaining words that match the pattern, return the fallback guess
        if not self.current_dictionary:
            return self.ensemble_guess(clean_word)

        # Extract features from the clean word pattern
        features = self.extract_features(clean_word)
        # Convert the features to a 2D array (samples x features) to use with the neural network
        pattern_features = np.array(features).reshape(1, -1)

        # Initialize a list to store the predictions from different models
        predictions = []

        # Initialize a list to store the classifiers for the ensemble
        classifiers = []

        # Add the desired models to the ensemble classifiers list
        if 'dt' in models:
            classifiers.append(('DecisionTree', self.decision_tree_model))
        if 'rf' in models:
            classifiers.append(('RandomForest', self.random_forest_model))
        if 'svm' in models:
            classifiers.append(('SVM', self.svm_model))

        # Create a VotingClassifier with the selected models
        voting_classifier = VotingClassifier(estimators=classifiers, voting='hard')

        # Train the ensemble classifier with the current dictionary
        X = self.vectorizer.transform(self.current_dictionary)
        y = np.array([word[-1] for word in self.current_dictionary])
        voting_classifier.fit(X, y)

        # Use the trained ensemble model to make a prediction
        ensemble_prediction = voting_classifier.predict(pattern_features)

        # Get the count of each letter at each position in the current dictionary
        letter_counts = [{letter: sum(1 for word in self.current_dictionary if word[i] == letter) for letter in self.target_labels}
                        for i in range(len(clean_word))]

        # Choose the character with the highest count at the next position
        next_position = len(self.guessed_letters)

        # If all letters have been guessed, use fallback guess from full dictionary ordering
        if next_position >= len(letter_counts):
            return self.ensemble_guess(clean_word)

        # Calculate the conditional probabilities of each letter given the word pattern
        letter_probabilities = {}
        total_letter_count = sum(letter_counts[next_position].values())
        for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            if letter not in self.guessed_letters:
                matching_words_count = letter_counts[next_position].get(letter, 0)
                conditional_probability = matching_words_count / total_letter_count
                # Calculate the information gain using entropy (log2)
                information_gain = -conditional_probability * math.log2(conditional_probability) if conditional_probability > 0 else 0
                letter_probabilities[letter] = information_gain

        # Choose the letter with the highest information gain as the next guess
        guessed_letter = max(letter_probabilities, key=letter_probabilities.get)

        return guessed_letter

    def compute_conditional_probabilities(self, word_pattern):
        # Count the occurrence of each letter in the possible words
        full_dict_string = "".join(self.current_dictionary)
        c = collections.Counter(full_dict_string)

        # Calculate the total count of letters in the possible words
        total_letter_count = sum(c.values())

        # Calculate the conditional probabilities of each letter given the word pattern
        letter_probabilities = {}
        for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            if letter not in self.guessed_letters:
                pattern_with_letter = word_pattern.replace(".", letter)
                matching_words_count = sum(1 for word in self.current_dictionary if re.match(pattern_with_letter, word))
                conditional_probability = matching_words_count / total_letter_count
                # Calculate the information gain using entropy (log2)
                information_gain = -conditional_probability * math.log2(conditional_probability) if conditional_probability > 0 else 0
                letter_probabilities[letter] = information_gain

        return letter_probabilities

    def build_dictionary(self, dictionary_file_location):
        text_file = open(dictionary_file_location, "r")
        full_dictionary = text_file.read().splitlines()
        text_file.close()
        return full_dictionary
```

1. **init**(self, access_token=None, session=None, timeout=None):
   The constructor initializes the HangmanAPI object. It sets up the API URL, access token, and session for making HTTP requests to the Hangman game server. It also loads a full dictionary of words and initializes machine learning models (Decision Tree, Random Forest, SVM) and a Q-table for reinforcement learning.
2. update_q_table(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
   This function updates the Q-values in the Q-table using the Q-learning update rule.
3. extract_features(self, word_pattern):
   Extracts features from the given word pattern to be used by machine learning models for making guesses.
4. hyperparameter_tuning(self):
   Performs hyperparameter tuning for the Decision Tree, Random Forest, and SVM models using Bayesian optimization.
5. genetic_algorithm_tuning(self):
   Performs hyperparameter tuning for the Decision Tree, Random Forest, and SVM models using a genetic algorithm.
6. train_all_models(self):
   Trains all the machine learning models, performs hyperparameter tuning, and trains a convolutional neural network (CNN) model.
7. word_to_numeric(self, word):
   Converts a word pattern to a binary sequence of guessed (1) and not guessed (0) letters.
8. ensemble_guess(self, word_pattern):
   Makes a guess for the given word pattern using an ensemble of Decision Tree, Random Forest, and SVM models.
9. determine_hangman_url(self):
   Determines the Hangman game server URL to be used based on response times to different server URLs.
10. train_neural_network(self):
    Trains a convolutional neural network (CNN) model using features extracted from the current dictionary of words.
11. fine_tune_neural_network(self):
    Fine-tunes the neural network model using features extracted from the current dictionary of words.
12. guess(self, word):
    Makes a guess for the given word pattern using the Q-learning algorithm and the current state of the game.
13. make_decision(self, word_pattern, models=['dt', 'rf', 'svm'], use_neural_net=True):
    Makes a guess for the given word pattern using an ensemble of machine learning models and the Q-learning algorithm.
14. compute_conditional_probabilities(self, word_pattern):
    Computes the conditional probabilities of each letter given the word pattern.
15. build_dictionary(self, dictionary_file_location):
    Loads a full dictionary of words from a text file.

I am trying to improve the accuracy above 10% to atleast 50%. I tried implementing multiple techniques together and choosing the one that works best based on scoring mechanism and then hyper-tuning the parameters. I also tried reinforcement learning, yet the result is abysmally low.

All suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Decision trees: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-tree/

Comment: @PålGD thank you so much, but what under decision tree do you want me to have a look? Decision Tree Classifier or Regressor? I am very new to these aspects. It'll be very helpful if you can help me implement these along the path. I have tried implementing basic decision tree concept here, if you can have a look and make recommendations

Comment: Please state the problem you are trying to solve clearly.  Your edits make the problem statement harder for me to understand.   This is not a coding site and code is off-topic here.  Please remove all code and replace it with algorithms, ideas, and concise pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a brute-force greedy algorithm, where you brute-force explore all possible guesses and all possible candidates for the secret word and see which guess leads to the most ambiguity about the secret word.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Algorithms_and_strategies, [Mastermind (board game) - Five-guess algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18749/755), https://stackoverflow.com/q/1185634/781723, https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.00557.

Comment: I've tried implementing reinforcement learning, and using different scores/probabilities to get the accurate letter using random forest/decision tree/SVM. I have tried implementing hyper parameter tuning along with some complicated techniques too yet the accuracy achieved is not greater than 10% If you can take a look and help improve the code

Comment: My python notebook can be found here: https://iitk-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/devbhavin20_iitk_ac_in/EUoYwxR00-1KrHcDXdEgOcABRl17EDA9o70g7z99zLNpHA?e=JipZyo

Comment: to add the file with 250000 words to train can be found here: https://iitk-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/devbhavin20_iitk_ac_in/EbDnTyKFdehBjlVYZMLgkckB4yKhszwMkV8ZWwF1-wzwdQ?e=0MLCSv

Comment: @driver, I'm suggesting a totally different approach and totally different algorithm.  This is not a coding site and I'm not available to review your code.